# Write a better preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression

I have this html code

```
<span><style>
.p9Wu{display:none}
.JOz4{display:inline}
.nitJ{display:none}
.pIj0{display:inline}
.AU2Q{display:none}
.vDdS{display:inline}
.THa1{display:none}
.mRy1{display:inline}
</style><span style="display: inline">69</span><span class="JOz4">.</span><span style="display:none">21</span><div style="display:none">21</div><span style="display: inline">65</span><span style="display:none">212</span><span class="AU2Q">212</span><span style="display: inline">.</span><span class="144">46</span><span style="display:none">69</span><span class="237">.</span><span style="display:none">11</span><span class="AU2Q">11</span><div style="display:none">11</div><div style="display:none">36</div><span style="display: inline">60</span><div style="display:none">152</div></span>
```

When view on the browser, it shows this 69.65.46.60
I want to use PHP to strip out html and left only text 69.65.46.60

First problem that I don't know how to write a pattern to get class the display:none
Second problem that my preg_replace is too long. Can someone help me to make it shorter? Thanks

This is my php code

```
$html = preg_replace('~<div([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']p9Wu["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</div>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<div([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']nitJ["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</div>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<div([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']AU2Q["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</div>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<div([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']THa1["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</div>~i', '', $html);

$html = preg_replace('~<span([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']p9Wu["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</span>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<span([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']nitJ["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</span>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<span([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']AU2Q["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</span>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<span([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']THa1["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</span>~i', '', $html);

$html = preg_replace('~<div([^>]*)(style\\s*=\\s*["\']display:none["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</div>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<span([^>]*)(style\\s*=\\s*["\']display:none["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</span>~i', '', $html);

$html = preg_replace('@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu', '', $html);

$html = strip_tags($html);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crunch your divs and spans together like so:

```
$html = preg_replace('~<(div|span)([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\'](p9Wu|nitJ|AU2Q|THa1)["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</\1>~i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('~<(div|span)([^>]*)(style\\s*=\\s*["\']display:none["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</\1>~i', '', $html);

$html = preg_replace('@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu', '', $html);

$html = strip_tags($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this like this way

for opening span tags use this preg

```
preg_replace('~\<span[^\>]*\>~is', '', $html);
```

for closing span tags use this preg

```
preg_replace('~\<\/span\>~is', '', $html);
```

for opening div tags use this preg

```
preg_replace('~\<div[^\>]*\>~is', '', $html);
```

for closing div tags use this preg

```
preg_replace('~\<\/div\>~is', '', $html);
```

for without style tags use this

```
preg_replace('/<style\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>/is', "", $html);
```

Hope this will help it will strip all tags and only text will remains...